# f# check if dir is accessible is not working

Tags: f#, directory

```
try (box (Directory.GetDirectories(dir) ))
with | :? System.UnauthorizedAccessException -> ()
```

I'm trying to check if the directory is accessible so I won't get an "access denied" error, but it's not working, it's not skipping the loop in for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have some other issues, if you have an exception the `try-with` block should be able to handle it, so either you're actually not getting an exception or have some other issues in the surrounding code. Why do you `box`?

The aversion to using exceptions as control flow makes some sense in .NET. in OCaml exceptions are used extensively for that purpose, but they are cheap. In .NET this is more expensive in performance terms. That said, sometimes you do want catch and handle an exception, so I don't think it's such a big issue. This for example works:

```
open System.IO
let okdir = @"c:\tmp"
let baddir = @"L:\Finance"

let checkDir dir = 

    try 
        Directory.GetDirectories(dir) |> ignore
        printfn "%A" "Processed"
    with 
        | :? System.UnauthorizedAccessException as ex -> failwith ex.Message
        | :? System.IO.IOException as ex -> failwith ex.Message 
    //    | :? System.Exception as ex -> failwith ex.Message

checkDir okdir
//"Processed"
//val it : unit = ()

checkDir baddir
//System.Exception: Access to the path 'L:\Finance' is denied.
```

Answer (score 3):

It's generally discouraged to use exceptions as part of your control flow.  It's better to check for the appropriate access to the directory before trying to enumerate its contents.  Try something like this:

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.Linq
open System.Security.AccessControl
open System.Security.Principal

let checkSecurity  =
    let account = sprintf @"%s\%s" Environment.UserDomainName Environment.UserName
    let identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
    let principal = identity |> WindowsPrincipal
    let isAdmin = identity.Owner = identity.User
    fun (dir: DirectoryInfo) ->
        try
            let acl = dir.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.All)
            let rules = acl.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof<NTAccount>)
            rules.OfType<FileSystemAccessRule>() 
            |> Seq.filter (fun rule -> rule.IdentityReference.Value.Equals(account, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) || 
                           (if rule.IdentityReference.Value.Equals("BUILTIN\Administrators", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) 
                            then isAdmin && principal.IsInRole(rule.IdentityReference.Value)
                            else principal.IsInRole(rule.IdentityReference.Value)))
            |> Seq.exists (fun rule -> (rule.FileSystemRights &&& FileSystemRights.Read = FileSystemRights.Read) && rule.AccessControlType <> AccessControlType.Deny)
        with | _ -> 
            false

let rec getFiles (dir: DirectoryInfo) =
    [ if checkSecurity dir
      then for file in dir.GetFiles("*") do yield file
           for subDir in dir.GetDirectories("*") do yield! getFiles subDir
    ]

let dir = DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Temp")
dir |> getFiles
```